# How do I print a value in an array in DDS

Tags: rpgle, rpg

I know this question isn't directly RPG language oriented, but I have no idea where I would turn otherwise.

I've created a PRTF in RDi for my project in class. I've set up several arrays in the RPGLE file to hold some numbers and several more like this example.

```
Dcl-s Freshman  Packed(5:0) Dim(4);
```

How do I specify that I want to print Freshman(2) in my PRTF?

I have tried things similar to these in the Functions section: Freshman(1), REFFLD(Freshman(1)), REFFLD(Freshman/1)

Answer (score 1):

A DDS based object (PRTF/DSPF/PF/LF) can only use a database file as a reference.

Otherwise, you need to define the field explicitly in the PRTF.
     `A            FRSHMAN        5S 0    182`

Now your RPG program could use the DDS defined field as a reference...
`Dcl-s Freshman  like(frshman) Dim(4);`

or you could leave it explicitly defined as originally posted.

Either way, you'd need to manually move the data in your RPG program.
  `frshman = Freshman(1);`